# Can I use update statement in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently is it possible to use Spark SQL to execute UPDATE queries on the database? For instance, update all values on a column in a table. I have the database JDBC url and credentials.

I did see some posts back from 2016 but I am not sure if they are accurate at this time. Thanks for the input :).

Comment: Spark doesn't support the updating of RDBMS by itself, you might have to use the dataframe and the supporting library i.e cx_oracle for oracle to update the records to the database.

Comment: see if you can use Delta Lake, and then later replicate it to RDBMS..  I think that is the only option

Comment: Which database it is based on database you can use insert or update for example MySQL has this feature

Comment: Oh the database is MySQL. Sorry.